# How to segue to a view controller by touching a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I segue to a view controller by touching a view embedded inside my view controller's view? It's easy to do this with a UIButton but not a UIView. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `subview` then `performSegue` in the selector method.

```
subview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleViewTap)))
```

Then:

```
@objc func handleViewTap() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)
}
```